# How to add different sets of parameters into the main() function?

Tags: c

I'm creating a program in C which will calculate something based on an equation with 4 sets of pre-set parameters. These pre-set parameters go into the main() function, however, I'm not entirely sure how to set them up. I'm assuming that once i've done it for one set of parameters, it'd be the same for the rest but just with different parameters.

Could someone point me in the right direction or give me some tips regarding this? I've looked up how to multiply two numbers together and then try to apply it to my case, but my numbers are pre-set and not input by the user, as well as there being more than just the main() function involved.

This is my code so far:

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    void equation(double rstar, double fp, int ne, double fone, double fi, double fc, int l)
    {
        X = rstar * fp * ne * fone * fi * fc * l;
    }

    int main(int argc, char **argv)
    {

    }
```

Comment: So, what you're asking is essentially how to call your function? Is that right? That's pretty basic, and I would imagine any tutorial that shows you how to define a function would also show you how to call it.

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/ ... and to be more specific: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_functions.htm

Comment: You could use a loop? `double rstar[4]; double fp[4]; for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) { equation(rstar[i], fp[i], ...); }`?

Comment: Edited the post.

Comment: Hint: [`atof`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/atof) on `argv[1]` and such. Arguments are always strings, so you need to convert if necessary. You may need `atoi` as well for integer arguments, plus checks that all arguments are present (e.g. `argc == 8`).

Comment: As I understand you want to pass seven parameters to `equation()` but you don't understand how the `main()` can take six parameters from user?

Comment: Yes! i'm terrible at explaining :/ main() will have 4 different sets of 7 parameters which are pre-assigned (unless by user you mean the programmer) which are then passed on to equation(), the function is called and the output of the equation is returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I have understood is you want to create a program which will have one equation, with a fixed set of parameters and the value of those parameters may vary according to the user.

We can do this in 2 steps.
1. Create a function which will perform the calculation on the equation
2. Ask the user to enter the value

First we will see the general type

```
return type/void func_name(parameter1,parameter2,....)
{
    Statements//whatever you want to do 
   //returning any value, if you chose a return type
}
int main()
{
  ask the user to enter the value
  call the function which you previously created
  catch the value if you are returning from the function
  end the main function
 }
```

Here is the main code, feel free to ask if something is unclear//

```
#include <stdio.h>
void equation(double rstar, double fp, int ne, double fone, double fi, double fc, int l)
{
    double X = rstar * fp * ne * fone * fi * fc * l;
    printf("\n\nAnswer is %lf",X);//  \n means next line
}
int main() 
{
   double rstar,fp,fone,fi,fc;
   int ne,l;
   printf("Enter rstar \n");
    scanf("%lf",&rstar);
    printf("Enter fp \n");
    scanf("%lf",&fp);
    printf("Enter ne \n");
    scanf("%d",&ne);
    printf("Enter fone\n");
    scanf("%lf",&fone);
    printf("Enter fi \n");
    scanf("%lf",&fi);
    printf("Enter fc \n");
    scanf("%lf",&fc);
    printf("Enter l \n");
    scanf("%d",&l);
   //you can write the above lines like this too
   //printf("Enter rstar fp.........");
   //scanf("%lf %lf %d %lf %lf %lf %lf %d",&rstar,&fp,&ne,&fone,&fi,&fc,&l);
  equation(rstar,fp,ne,fone,fi,fc,l);
  return 0;
}
```

I have written the code to help you in case you get stuck, don't just copy it.

Comment: I think I understand what you've done here. Does the line equation(rstar,fp,ne,fone,fi,fc,l); basically call the equation function and "moves" the variables between the brackets there so that the calculation can then be performed? Also, how would I do it if the values for the 7 parameters are not entered in by the user, as I have a table with 4 sets of parameters which are already pre-determined rather than being input by the user. I was thinking of instead of having printf("Enter rstar \n"); to have something like rstar = <value> and then scanf("%lf",&rstar);

Comment: when we call the function and pass a variable or a value, it does not move the values there,it simply passes the value to that function.Passing the value means,function which is being called can use those values in whatever manner they want,but they can't change the original value. For the fixed values, you can do either of two things,create a variable and then assign them values, or simply pass the values from the calling function. for ex, rstar=2.2;fp=1.3;...equation(rstar,fp....) or no mention of rstar,fp in the main fn, just equation(2.2,1.3...

Comment: So if I was to pass the values from the calling function, would my calling function look something like this: equation(rstar=2.2; fp=1.3; etc) or would I need to separate out the calling bit and the assigning of the values?

Comment: No. You can either pass the value or the variable for a particular spot,at a particular time. Check this link, this has the same program which I wrote here but in a different way, it will clear your doubt, https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/eOjZqThamR

Comment: Thanks a lot for the link. From what I understood from it, you showed me two ways of passing the values across into the equation() function, through the user input and also putting them into the equation() call at the bottom of main. I've changed it around for what I think i'd need to do and came out with this: https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/IEby3myHEc . I checked the answer manually as well and it all adds up to the same value so it seems to work.

Comment: Just a minor correction, since you are passing the values, remove the variables from the main function as they don't have any meaning now. Rest is fine.

Comment: Alright thanks a lot. Just one more thing, in the part where the answer is displayed, I'd need to display the answer along with the numbers used to calculate the answer, for example, "X = <answer>, rstar = 1.1, fp = 2.2" and so on. Do the arguments in equation(1.1,2.2 etc) correspond to the order of the variables in the equation() function or will I need to do it differently for this to happen?

Comment: printf(" x=%lf , rstar= %lf.....",x,rstar....); Order of the variable is important, calling function should pass the arguments in the same order they are declared in the function header. Changing the order will not result in compilation error in some cases where the type of the variables is same but will definitely generate runtime/logical error.

Answer (score 2):

So you want your function to accept one of 4 sets of predefined parameters.  The first thing to do is define the parameter sets:

```
struct param_set {
    double rstar;
    double fp;
    int ne;
    double fone;
    double fi;
    double fc;
    int l;
};

struct param_set set[4] = {
    { 1.2, 3.4, 5, 6.6, 7.7, 8.8, 9 },
    { 11.2, 13.4, 15, 16.6, 17.7, 18.8, 19 },
    { 21.2, 23.4, 25, 26.6, 27.7, 28.8, 29 },
    { 31.2, 33.4, 35, 36.6, 37.7, 38.8, 39 }
};
```

Then in your main function, you select a set and pass them to the function:

```
int set_number = 2;   // or whichever set you want to work with

equation(set[set_number].rstar, set[set_number].fp, set[set_number].ne, 
         set[set_number].fone, set[set_number].fi, set[set_number].fc, set[set_number].l);
```